# How and which database to use with NWjs offline windows app to store data

Tags: mongodb, electron, nwjs, database

i made a simplest application in nwjs which just takes an input of name .
now i can't store this value permanently because app is not connected with any database .
i know about mongodb but don't know how to integrate with javascript app.
i watched some tutorials how to use mongodb with apps but they in tutorials always use cmd to first start server (now a general software don't require , user to start servers manually etc).
Please help me if there is a way to store, fetch and perform other operations on data offline.
what i am missing ? Thanks

Comment: I encourage you to format a bit more your question with paragraphs, caps ect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for:

- [NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb), a Mongo-like offline in-memory database
- [LinvoDB3](https://github.com/Ivshti/linvodb3), same than NeDB, but not in-memory (slower, but more scalable in terms of size)
- [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) a Web API

Comment: thanks ! i think NeDB is the one i need . but i'm not understanding the difference between Embedded persistent or in memory database ! which should i use ? what i want is to store data permanently (maybe in a file). so that if i close nwjs app or shout down pc , still on relaunch i should able to access my data .

Comment: You will want to use the persistent part of NeDB. All your database will be in a single file whereever you want

Comment: yes i got it after a bit of search :) just one last thing please . i am the developer so i have node.js installed so that i can use this database . is it also necessary after the complete development of software for user's computer to have node.js installed to use software ? thanks a lot for the quick reply !

Comment: NeDB can only be used if you have a write access on the system you operate. (Node, Electron...). A browser can't do that, and won't be able to have a persistent database, at least not with NeDB. You may take a look at IndexedDB and LocalStorate for that. But usually, keeping stuff on client side is not a good idea.